Issues Disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on Tomcat Server
I'm managing a website, and during a vulnerability scan, it's showing that TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are still supported. However, I'm trying to disable these protocols to improve security.
I don't have much knowledge about security, but I've tried several things (with help from ChatGPT), and nothing seems to be working.
Additional Information:

Server: Tomcat 8.5.100

Java Version: java 8


please help me.
Steps I've Taken to Solve This:

Modified the server.xml file as follows:
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" server="Server" />
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    keystoreFile="/path" keystorePass="password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
               Ciphers="ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,
         ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,
         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,
         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384,
         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
/>


Setting protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" doesn't seem to work.

I tried removing the ciphers attribute, but it didn't help.

I also tried using the <SSLHostConfig> tag, but Tomcat failed to restart. I Checked the catalina.log and saw this error:
Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [_default_]. Hostnames must be unique.




java.security file
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL


Tested with the openssl command, and the session protocol is TLSv1.2



Yes the old blocking implementation Http11Protocol is no longer available in 8.5. Assuming you mean openssl s_client that by default negotiates the highest shared protocol which doesn't give any info about lower protocols. Try adding -tls1 (for 1.0) or -tls1_1 (for 1.1) and see if those work. If they don't, your scan is a false positive. Is your server in an environment that has any kind of protection (WAF, IDS/IPS, antivirus) or frontend (loadbalancer, CDN)?

Because you have a bit older environment, and to echo the comment from @dave_thompson_085, a simple answer may be to put something like Apache HTTPD in front so that you can control the SSL from it.  Current versions of Apache can handle TLS 1.3 which is more than your current environment can.

@stdunbar: Tomcat 8.5 is oldish, but based on the java.security setting OP is almost certainly running Java 8u291 or higher, and 8u261 up supports TLS1.3 if the app is (re)configured to use/allow it -- assuming they are using JSSE (i.e. APR isn't enabled elsewhere)
